# Upgrading subscription using react-native-iap package

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase, google-play-console, react-native-iap

Good evening developers,

I have an existing app with a subscription plan on Google Play Console with around 1000 users. Let's just say it is `Plan A`. Now, I want to introduce another tier of subscription, let's call it `Plan B`.
`Plan B` has a few more features than `Plan A`. I read on https://react-native-iap.dooboolab.com/docs/api_reference/methods API reference that `requestSubscription()` is probably my best bet to upgrade a user's subscription plan from `A` to `B`.

Question 1: Does that mean when I use `requestSubscription()` with `ProrationModesAndroid` as `DEFERRED` my current (`Plan A`) subscribers will be reset?

Question 2: Is there a cleaner way to upgrade a user's subscription plan from `A` to `B`? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1: Your current (plan A) will be changed to (Plan B)...  When you upgrade or downgrade the subscription with requestSubscription and DEFERRED Proration Mode, Google Play billing dialog will show the subscription plan is changed successfully, and you will receive a notification email from Google Play about that.

reference: https://flutterrepos.com/lib/dooboolab-react-native-iap

Answer 2: It seems to be the cleaner way